# Retrieve word from string

Tags: php, string

I have this code:

```
$getClass = $params->get('pageclass_sfx');
var_dump($getClass); die();
```

The code above returns this:

```
string(24) "sl-articulo sl-categoria"
```

How can I retrieve the specific word I want without mattering its position?

Ive seen people use arrays for this but that would depend on the position (I think) that you enter these strings and these positions may vary.

For example:

```
$myvalue = $params->get('pageclass_sfx');
$arr = explode(' ',trim($myvalue));
echo $arr[0];
```

`$arr[0]` would return: sl-articulo

`$arr[1]` would return: sl-categoria

Thanks.

Comment: Regular expressions would be a way to go.

Comment: What's wrong with the current approach? Does `explode()` not satisfy your requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use substr for that in combination with strpos:

https://www.php.net/substr

https://www.php.net/strpos

```php
$word = 'sl-categoria';
$page_class_sfx = $params->get('page_class_sfx');      
if (false !== ($pos = strpos($page_class_sfx, $word))) {
    // stupid because you already have the word... But this is what you request if I understand correctly
    echo 'found: ' . substr($page_class_sfx, $pos, strlen($word)); 
}
```

Not sure if you want to get a word from the string if you already know the word... You want to know if it's there? `false !== strpos($page_class_sfx, $word)` would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you know exactly what strings you're looking for, then `stripos()` should be sufficient (or `strpos()` if you need case-sensitivity). For example:

```
$myvalue = $params->get('pageclass_sfx');

$pos = stripos($myvalue, "sl-articulo");
if ($pos === FALSE) {
    // string "sl-articulo" was not found
} else {
    // string "sl-articulo" was found at character position $pos
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check if some word are in string you may use `preg_match` function.

```
if (preg_match('/some-word/', 'many some-words')) {
    echo 'some-word';
}
```

But this solution can be used for a small list of needed words.

For other cases i suggest you to use some of this.

```
$myvalue = $params->get('pageclass_sfx');
$arr = explode(' ',trim($myvalue));
$result = array();
foreach($arr as $key=> $value) {
    // This will calculates all data in string.
    if (!isset($result[$value])) {
        $result[$value] = array(); // or 0 if you don`t need to use positions
    }
    $result[$value][] = $key; // For all positions
    // $result[$value] ++; // For count of this word in string
}

// You can just test some words like follow:
if (isset($result['sl-categoria'])) {
    var_dump($result['sl-categoria']);
}
```